# Dont work autocomplete with twitter-typeahead-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-typeahead

The user specifies the city. Autocomplete should occur by the first letters entered.

If input in field first letters, for example "Ber...", nothing happens.

How me run script for search and autocomplete cities?

I specifed gem as dependency in Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require json2
//= require judge
//= require registration
//= require jquery-ui
//= require tag-it
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require twitter/typeahead
//= require freelancers
//= require response
//= require projects
//= require cities_germany
//= require turbolinks
```

**assets/javascript/cities_germany.js**

```
var cities = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('num'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: [{ city: 'Berlin (Berlin)'},
          { city: 'Hamburg (Hamburg)'},
          { city: 'München (Bavaria)'}, 
          { city: 'Köln (Northrhine-Westfalia)'},
          { city: 'Frankfurt (Hessen)'}, 
          { city: 'Essen    (Northrhine-Westfalia)'}, 
          { city: 'Dortmund (Northrhine-Westfalia)'},
          { city: 'Stuttgart (Baden-Württemberg)'}, 
          { city: 'Düsseldorf   Northrhine-Westfalia'}, 
          { city: 'Bremen (Bremen)'},
          { city: 'Hannover (Lower Saxony)'}, 
          { city: 'Duisburg (Northrhine-Westfalia)'}, 
          { city: 'Nürnberg (Bavaria)'},
          { city: 'Leipzig  (Saxony)'}, 
          { city: 'Dresden  (Saxony)'}
          ]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
cities.initialize();

$('#main-cities .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'city',
  source: cities.ttAdapter()
});
```

I added in form html next field:

```
<li class="form-fields__group form-fields__group_full">
              <%= f.label 'City' %>
              <div class="field" id="main-cities">
                <%= f.text_field :location, class: 'typeahead' %>
              </div>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I founded error:

replaced numbers.initialize() to cities.initialize();  and whitespace('num') to whitespace('city')